# Include links in exported excel file

Tags: excel, coldfusion, export-to-excel, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I am creating a query and then downloading it into an excel document. I would like to include some links inside the excel document but cannot figure out how to do it. I tried just putting an anchor tag in the `querySetCell()` value, but that just prints the html inside the excel file, the html does not get parsed. I'm using CF10. Below is my code, any advice is appreciated.

```
<cfset q = queryNew("#columnNames#")>

<cfset queryAddRow(q)>
<cfset querySetCell(q, "Attributes", "Part Number")>
<cfset querySetCell(q, "PrimaryPart", "#local.primaryPart.getProductNumber()#")>
<cfset i = 0>
<cfloop array="#local.comparableParts#" index="part">
    <cfset i++>
    <cfset querySetCell(q, "alternatePart"& i, "#part.getPartNumber()#")>
</cfloop>

<cfspreadsheet action="write" query="q" filename="partCompare.xls" overwrite="true" />

<!--- Make a spreadsheet object --->
<cfset s = spreadsheetNew()>
<!--- Add header row --->
<cfset spreadsheetAddRow(s, "#columnNames#")>
<!--- format header --->    
<cfset spreadsheetFormatRow(s, {bold=true, fgcolor="lemon_chiffon"}, 1)>

<cfset spreadsheetAddRows(s, q)>

<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=partCompare.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(s)#" reset="true">
```

**UPDATE**:
I made some changes to my code based on the comments. The links do show up in the excel document now, but the 'friendly name' shows as a 0 until I click the 'enable editing' button in excel. It would be nice if the friendly name is displayed from the beginning but if it is not possible, or depends on user settings, this should be fine.

```
<cfset partCompareQueryObj = queryNew("#columnNames#")>

<cfset queryAddRow(partCompareQueryObj)>
<cfset querySetCell(partCompareQueryObj, "Attributes", "Part Number")>
<cfset querySetCell(partCompareQueryObj, "PrimaryPart", "#local.primaryPart.getProductNumber()#")>
<cfset i = 0>
<cfloop array="#local.comparableParts#" index="part">
    <cfset i++>
    <cfset querySetCell(partCompareQueryObj, "alternatePart"& i, "#part.getPartNumber()#")>
</cfloop> 

<cfspreadsheet action="write" query="partCompareQueryObj" filename="partCompare.xls" overwrite="true" />

<!--- Make a spreadsheet object --->
<cfset partCompareSpreadSheet = spreadsheetNew()>

<!--- Add header row --->
<cfset spreadsheetAddRow(partCompareSpreadSheet, "#columnNames#")>
<!--- format header --->    
<cfset spreadsheetFormatRow(partCompareSpreadSheet, {bold=true, fgcolor="lemon_chiffon"}, 1)>

<cfset spreadsheetAddRows(partCompareSpreadSheet, partCompareQueryObj)>

<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellFormula(partCompareSpreadSheet, 'HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","#local.primaryPart.getProductNumber()#")', 2, 2)>
<cfset i = 0>
<cfloop array="#local.comparableParts#" index="part">
    <cfset i++>
    <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellFormula(partCompareSpreadSheet, 'HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","#local.primaryPart.getProductNumber()#")', 2, i+2)>
</cfloop>

<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=partCompare.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(partCompareSpreadSheet)#" reset="true">
```

Comment: It seems to me that you probably need to use the Excel `HYPERLINK` function. So, adding `=HYPERLINK(link_location,friendly_name)` to your cell should get you what. (I don't have a system to hand to test.)

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce That almost works. It prints the function in plain text at first but once I click on the cell and hit enter, it runs the function and creates the link. Kind of strange behavior IMO..

Comment: Is the call to hyperlink() wrapped with SpreadsheetSetCellFormula()?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno The call was not wrapped, but it is now and the link works. However, the friendly name is displayed as '0' until the 'enable editing' button is clicked in excel. Is there anything I can do about that? I updated the question with the new code.

Comment: I don't think there is anything I can do about excel opening in *Protected View* as it is an excel setting. So can one of you write up an answer and I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to wrap a call to Excel's Hyperlink() function with a call to ColdFusion's SpreadsheetSetCellFormula() function.

```
<cfset spreadsheetSetCellFormula(sheetName
                  , 'HYPERLINK(url, linkText)'
                  , rowNumber
                  , columnNumber)>
```